# How to find out date in which URL was shortened

Tags: datetime, url-shortener

may I know how do you find out when a particular URL was shortened using Bitly?

Answer (score 16):

Just add "+" to the end of the URL in your browser

Answer (score 0):

The [`info` endpoint](https://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_info) for the API includes that information as `...data.info[0].created_at`.

Comment: Hi Quentin, thanks for the prompt reply! I only have the link of the shortened URL, and I am not the one who shortened the link, may I know if there is any way to find that out? Apologies for asking the question as I am not familiar with IT. Thanks much in advance!

Comment: @YueYouTham — The example code on the documentation linked to in this answer shows that the only input is the shortened URL.